# How to remove query strings from static resources on an HTML5 website

Tags: html, apache

I've learned web development on WordPress and started getting back into creating more basic websites by hard coding using HTML5, CSS, and JS. While trying to diagnose issues on tools.pingdom.com for a non-WordPress site, I get an error:

Remove Query Strings from Static Resources:

> //p.typekit.net/p.gif?s=1&k=tel3vyz&app=t...15.6817.6818&a=904365&js=1.18.15&_=1488301070618
>   //use.typekit.net/af/5754c8/0000000000000...T%2FUVxUXoROYYlPX9iPREeE4eTj8ZPHMcljmzx28Q%3D%3D
>   //use.typekit.net/af/605658/0000000000000...T%2FUVxUXoROYYlPX9iPREeE4eTj8ZPHMcljmzx28Q%3D%3D
>   //use.typekit.net/af/6f3fd7/0000000000000...T%2FUVxUXoROYYlPX9iPREeE4eTj8ZPHMcljmzx28Q%3D%3D
>   //use.typekit.net/af/9498c4/0000000000000...T%2FUVxUXoROYYlPX9iPREeE4eTj8ZPHMcljmzx28Q%3D%3D
>   //use.typekit.net/af/b318b4/0000000000000...T%2FUVxUXoROYYlPX9iPREeE4eTj8ZPHMcljmzx28Q%3D%3D

Any ideas on how I can address these? I should add that this isn't a WordPress site. I would know how to address this on a WordPress site but not on a static HTML website.